# Retrieve Alljoyn Device Names and Amount of Devices in Channel on Android

Tags: java, android, networking, alljoyn

We created a game for socialising on android using the alljoyn chat examples for sending messages between all devices. Now we need an improved method for retrieving the amount and names of devices in the current channel.

I am unable to retrieve it from the API itself which is why right now we are sending random messages from each connected device for a few seconds until a unique name is found for each of them.

This seems to be not optimal and not how it should work. 
The Java documentation is at: https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/api-guide/core/java

And the Chat Sample at: 
https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/run-sample-apps/chat/android